# String modification in APIGEE edge without using Javascript

Tags: apigee

I was wondering on there was an keyword like lower() in apigee edge to change the value to lowercase to check in conditional flow

[http://api.com/{uriparam}?Action=Lower](http://api.com/%7Buriparam%7D?Action=Lower)

lower(request.queryparam.Action) == "lower"

is there any way to achieve this without using any java script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apigee has its own operator for doing case insensitive matching. So you can just use `:=` instead of `==` and it will match your example.

```
request.queryparam.Action := "lower"
```

Also see the conditions reference from the Apigee documentation: https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/conditions-reference#operators